# Visual Studio + grunt - run tasks depending on configuration?

Tags: visual-studio, gruntjs

I've just start playing with grunt for visual studio and I can't figure out how to run particular tasks depending on configuration (debug, release, etc).

You can run tasks before build, after build, etc. But how to bind it to the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260774/injecting-content-via-grunt-task-depending-on-asp-net-project-build-configurati) might help.

On top of that I added this:

```
cd "$(SolutionDir)\CustomerService\Resources\build\node_modules"
call grunt.cmd chatStyling --buildConfiguration=$(ConfigurationName)
```

to my pre-build events. (Note that `chatStyling` is a custom task.)

Answer (score 0):

`<shameless-plug />` I do this using VsCommandBuddy extension for vs2013/vs2015. Using the configurationname in a macro as parameter for the command you'd like to execute.