# Injecting content via Grunt task, depending on asp.net project build configuration

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio, gruntjs

I'm trying to inject content via [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace) when I build by visual studio solution. However I would like to inject different content depending on the build configuration.

Is it possible to read the build configuration using grunt/node.

Thanks.

Comment: I realize this was already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706830/visual-studio-grunt-run-tasks-depending-on-configuration

but it was not answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grunt.option` for this. Provide your build env on the command line and use it in the Gruntfile using grunt.option.

Quoting the example from grunt.option [documentation](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option)

Gruntfile.js

```
grunt.initConfig({
  compass: {
    dev: {
      options: {
        /* ... */
        outputStyle: 'expanded'
      },
    },
    staging: {
      options: {
        /* ... */
        outputStyle: 'compressed'
      },
    },
  },
});
var target = grunt.option('target') || 'dev';
grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['compass:' + target]);
```

As you run grunt deploy your stylesheets would default to the dev target and output the CSS in the expanded format. If you ran `grunt deploy --target=staging` the staging target would instead be ran and your CSS would be in the compressed format.

```
grunt deploy --target=staging
```